# Could not deploy content data, Could not parse json package

Tags: publishing, deployerservice, sites-9.6

We have upgraded CM from Sites 9.1 to 9.6 and Created New DB's(Tridion_CM_96 , Tridion_Topology_96) for CM & Topology manager respectively.

We are trying to publish content after upgrade, but it's in "Committing Deployment" state only, Not changing to Success/Fail.
[image]We have verified the logs on Deployer service. its showing as below

`ERROR TransportPackage - Could not parse json package for tcm_0-461522-66560.Content com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "pages" (class com.tridion.transport.transportpackage.json.Package), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: "Templates", "Schemas", "Pages", "StructureGroups", "ComponentPresentations"]) at [Source: (sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream); line: 2, column: 13] (through reference chain: com.tridion.transport.transportpackage.json.Package["pages"])`

we did not change any configurations Post Upgrade CM. we did not do any changes on CD(Existing CD 9.1) as well.

Using Deployer, Discovery, session & Preview Microservices.
& Using Discovery, Broker & XPM Databases only.

Can you please suggest how to resolve above issue.

Answer (score 5):

As Confirmed by SDL Team, Rolling upgrades are only supported from the next version (9.5 -> 9.6) so a 9.1 deployer is not supported with 9.6 CM.